# Utilise functions across two Dart files

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, button

I'm trying to run a simple timer using the timer_controller and timer_count_down libraries. I'd like the keep the buttons in a separate file in order to keep the code clean, however when running the main app, the buttons no longer control the timer. I'd like to know how to 'import' those functions so to speak.

I've searched a few ways and found numerous sources, for example using
import 'package:sample/global.dart'; however, this didn't seem to exist when entering it into the dart file.

Page 1:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:timer_app/util/buttons.dart';
import 'package:timer_count_down/timer_controller.dart';
import 'package:timer_count_down/timer_count_down.dart';

class TimerTile extends StatefulWidget {
  const TimerTile({super.key});

  @override
  State<TimerTile> createState() => _TimerTilesState();
}

class _TimerTilesState extends State<TimerTile> {
  final CountdownController _controller =
      new CountdownController(autoStart: false);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 16,
            ),
            child: MyButtons(),
          ),
          Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 16,
              ),
              child: Countdown(
                  controller: _controller,
                  seconds: 5,
                  build: (_, double time) => Text(
                        time.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 100,
                        ),
                      )))
        ]);
  }
}
```

Page 2

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:timer_count_down/timer_controller.dart';
import 'package:timer_count_down/timer_count_down.dart';

class MyButtons extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyButtons({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyButtons> createState() => _MyButtonsState();
}

class _MyButtonsState extends State<MyButtons> {
  final CountdownController _controller =
      new CountdownController(autoStart: false);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly, children: [
      ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _controller.start();
          },
          child: Text('Start')),
      ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _controller.pause();
          },
          child: Text('Pause')),
      ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _controller.resume();
          },
          child: Text('Resume')),
      ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _controller.restart();
          },
          child: Text('Restart'))
    ]);
    ;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly which functions you're having trouble using, but if one dart file `import`s another file, it will have access to all *public* symbols (identifiers that don't start with `_`) in that file.